# InfluxDB, Telegraf, MQTT Consumer, JSON Plugin: JSON input losing precision on 64bit integers

Tags: json, floating-point, mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

I'm trying to send some MQTT data (JSON format) with Telegraf to InfluxDB. I'm using the the MQTT Consumer Input Plugin with Datatype JSON.

Data Example:

`{ "bsEui": 8121069193333309404 }`

In InfluxDB the data i get is:

`{ "bsEui": 8121069193333309000 }`

I suppose the problem is that the JSON parser is converting all JSON Numbers automatically to float64. Maybe somebody had the same issue and knows a good workaround?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like it is  rounding/displaying as rounded/truncated to 16 digits (8121069193333309404 => 8121069193333309000).  (Bad form, it should indicate this was done by displaying it as 8.121069193333309e18 IMHO.)  My 32 bit system rounds it to 8121069298811666432.  My 64 bit system rounds it to 8121069193333309440.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. I found a good workaround with python. For others who are facing the same issue, i recommend to use the new JSON_V2 (version 2) Parser. Telegraf found a solution to convert the numbers to int64.